# Time reference of imperatives/modals

Tags: descriptive-grammar

What time reference is indicated by imperative sentences/Sentences with modal verbs (present  or future)Some say it is present time others say it indicates future since the action can only happen after the time of speaking. 
Examples-
Do this work.
You must do it now
Will you stop talking? 
May i come in? etc
The above seems innocuous on the face of it but i have found many native experts differing on time reference. I am not referring to the tense part which is clear.

Comment: There is no time reference intrinsic to the verb forms themselves; time may be referred to in the rest of the sentence, of course.

Comment: Dear John, could you please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: If you say _He may be home by now_ you mean the present, because you said _now_. If you say _That might be true,_ you may be referring to some time in particular, but no listener will know whether, or which, unless they already know all the context. As for orders, by the nature of causality you can't change the past, so you can't give orders to anyone else to do it. Other than that, there is no specification of time in an imperative; in fact, imperatives are stripped down to the basics in most languages, and don't specify much of anything.